# Run sequentially cir and net files with tcl/tk

Tags: tcl, pspice, orcad

I would like to give me your advice about using cadence orcad
so I can run sequentially cir or net(netlist) files with pspice.exe in cmd of my pc.

I use tcl/tk language.I have tried a few things without any results.

I want to make something similar to this one:

```
set top  {C:\Users\file1.net C:\Users\file2.net}; 
foreach a $top 
{exec D:\\tools\\bin\\pspice.exe -r $a}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current attempt? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: That code isn' t running and to clarified it better I want to make that procedure : set top {C:\Users\new.net}; exec D:\\tools\\bin\\pspice.exe -r $top , for a few files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.
The first problem is that `\f` is an escape character sequence in lists (for “go down one line”, IIRC; point is you don't want that interpretation). The second problem is that you've got your brace placement wrong in your `foreach`.

The first problem is best addressed by using `/` instead of `\`, and then using `file nativename` on the value fed to the OS. (You have to do that manually for argument to executables in `expr`; Tcl can't fix that for you entirely automatically.) The second problem is just a syntax error.

Try this:

```
set top {C:/Users/file1.net C:/Users/file2.net}
set pspice D:/tools/bin/pspice.exe
foreach a $top {
    # Tcl knows how to convert executable names for you; not the other args though
    exec $pspice -r [file nativename $a]
}
```

Comment: Use “Ancient Egyptian” braces with Tcl unless you either know _exactly_ what you're doing, or really like fighting with the base language syntax.

Comment: I found your first problem by looking at what `lindex $top 0` returned.

Comment: Firstly thank you for your answer.Secondly the code above run and simulate only the first file of our list and that's the problem which I come up against.For example i want to make 20 *.net files to run and simulate under of pspice.exe from my cmd.

Comment: @paiktis30 Put a `&` at the end of `exec` line, like this: `exec $pspice -r [file nativename $a] &`

Comment: @Losko thank you for your anwser, that correction it works,but only for the first file of my list.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried what I wrote in the other answer? If you are able to open multiple documents inside PSpice (using Windows Explorer I mean) then you should give it a try, that's the closest thing possible... what happens normally if you double click on `*.net` files? TWAPI solution simulates exactly that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you may also try:

```
package require twapi

set top {C:/Users/file1.net C:/Users/file2.net}

foreach a $top {
    twapi::shell_execute -path [file nativename $a]
}
```

This will work only if `*.net` files are already associated with **PSpice** application.

The code above rely on **TWAPI** extension (if you have it) and its `shell_execute` function, to open a document just like double-click works.

It's always a good idea to avoid backslashes in your code (no need to put it twice to escape them), `file nativename` will do the job for you.

Source: https://twapi.magicsplat.com/v4.5/shell.html#shell_execute